# Firefox, Thunderbird, Safari - hangs up on start

Tags: windows-vista, firefox, thunderbird, safari

I have a strange problem on Windows Vista (Automatic updates).

Long time ago I had installed Firefox, Thunderbird, Safari and Opera and they all worked well.

Once upon a time, after Windows restart, Firefox, Thunderbird and Safari won't start. [Opera (USB) works fine].

When I start the browser, program name is listed on the processes list, but it is not activated, doesn't show any window.

I tried crating new profiles with `-ProfileManager`, restarting Windows, reinstalling the browsers. I scanned the system for suspected programs and it looks clean. There is 45GB of free HDD space.

WTF?

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted to uninstall the browsers, and then re-installing them?  If you don't uninstall sometimes fragments are not reinstalled....  It's rare, but it happens....

Also, check your permissions on the application support folders for those browsers...